# Need two JSON schemas which are Full compatible between each other

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm currently learning JSON Schemas need 2 sample schemas which are 'Full compatible' between each other.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't enough detail for us to understand how to help you. Try explaining in more detail and maybe adding an example.

Answer (score 0):

Schema A:

```
true
```

Schema B:

```
{ "not": false }
```